# How to get sum of field1 for unique values of field2 in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have index pattern in **kibana**. I want to get **SUM of one field** based on **UNIQUE values of second field**. How can I get this in kibana visualization.
As example :

```
{ server: 1, size: 813, @timestamp: "2018-12-28 09:00"}
{ server: 2, size: 654, @timestamp: "2018-12-28 09:00"}
{ server: 3, size: 752, @timestamp: "2018-12-28 09:00"}
{ server: 1, size: 915, @timestamp: "2018-12-28 10:00"}
{ server: 2, size: 823, @timestamp: "2018-12-28 10:00"}
{ server: 3, size: 783, @timestamp: "2018-12-28 10:00"}
```

I want solution like below :

```
(915 + 823 + 783 = 2521)
```

Any Solution ??

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried scripted field, DSL query, tsvb ... but I didnt get any correct solution. Plz tell me how can I solve this problem.